# Remove edgewidth of matplotlib boxplot flier

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

In the boxplot below, I would like to remove the black edges of the fliers (pink circles). However, it does not seem to work. Here's my code:

```
bp = plt.boxplot(boxes)
for flier in bp['fliers']:
    flier.set(marker = 'o', color = '#e7298a', alpha = 0.5, linewidth = 0.0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the style while generating the plots?

```
flierprops = dict(marker='o', markerfacecolor='green', markersize=12, linestyle='none')
```

or (both untested)

```
flierprops = dict(marker='o', fillstyle='full', markeredecolor='red', markeredgewidth=0.0)
```

then

```
boxplot(data, flierprops=flierprops)
```

Example from: http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/boxplot_demo.html